# TMP_TextUtilities fails to find entire link string

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm constructing links in certain texts in my game, using the `<link>` tag with TMP. These links contains a GUID in order to identify what it is pointing to.

```
<link=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx>Some text</link>
```

This is working for my most part but when there a `e` in the GUID TMP cuts off at the first occurrence, so for example if there was an `e` at position 10 TMP only manages to return the 10 first characters in the GUID.

This is what happens:

```
xxxxxxxx-xxex-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx-xx
```

The method generating the text

```
    public string CharacterLink(CharacterInfo info)
    {
        return $"<color={characterColor.Format()}><link={info.Id}>{info.Fullname}</link></color>";
    }
```

The methods for fetching the link

```
    public Entity GetLinkCharacter(TextMeshProUGUI text)
    {
        TMP_LinkInfo info = GetLink(text);
        if (info.Equals(default(TMP_LinkInfo)))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return entities.GetEntity(Guid.Parse(info.GetLinkID()));
    }

    private TMP_LinkInfo GetLink(TextMeshProUGUI text)
    {
        int index = TMP_TextUtilities.FindIntersectingLink(text, Input.mousePosition, null);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            return default;
        }

        return text.textInfo.linkInfo[index];
    }
```

Whenever there's an `e` in the GUID it throws an exception every time it tries to parse it since the GUID gets cut off on the first occurrence of an `e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of quotation marks was the issue. Silly me forgot to add them.

```
public string CharacterLink(CharacterInfo info)
{
    return $"<color={characterColor.Format()}><link={info.Id}>{info.Fullname}</link></color>";
}
```

had to be converted into this

```
public string CharacterLink(CharacterInfo info)
{
    return $"<color=\"{characterColor.Format()}\"><link=\"{info.Id}\">{info.Fullname}</link></color>";
}
```